# Прозрачная форма

Tags: xna

Привет всем. Скажите пожалуйста можно ли сделать в xna, прозрачную форму?

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае нет, потому что XNA не всегда рендерится на окно.

Даже если рендерится в окно, вы будете иметь кучу ограничений:

- DirectComposition — Win8+
- LayeredWindows, DesktopWindowManager — Vista+, с XNA вряд ли тривиально скрестить

[Разбор вариантов скрещивания прозрачности с DirectX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28009960/293099).